# Angular material stepper previous button does not work with linear

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I have a material stepper and the mode is set to linear.

next button is working just fine but the pevious button is not working.

I also tried to work with *matStepperPrevious* & *matStepperNext*

Link to the stackblitsz I created:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-galdj7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You are setting the first step to editable false. Remove the line and it works, or set editable true again when going back.

Comment: And how do set these (completed & editbale) values for a specific step. You can trigger the current /selected step but I do not know how you can set a specific step (by example by index)

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Thank you for the feedback I removed the "editble" line. This is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

adding to  @MoxxiManagarm comment youre setting [editable](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api) to flase
remove it and add this

```
 oneStepBack() {
 this.stepper.previous();
}
```

Comment: I already tried to use function.
If I do this the step wil never complete. Editbale will be false for al steps. I want to set this for a specific step (by index) and not for all.

Comment: do you want to editable to be false at the last step ?